# How to sort an array on a certain variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, variables

I have a  piece of a var_dump of one of my array items displayed here:

```
protected 'created_at' => 
object(Carbon\Carbon)[178]
public 'date' => string '2014-01-23 00:00:00' (length=19)
public 'timezone_type' => int 3
public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Amsterdam' (length=16)
```

my question is how can I sort this array on the `created_at` variable?
it should be descending.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) should do the trick!

See the working example **[here](http://ideone.com/dSfnHe)**.

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
  $first = $a['created_at']->format('U');
  $second= $b['created_at']->format('U');

  if ($first == $second) {
    return 0;
  }

  return ($first < $second) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

The callback is using the date's timestamp (`->format('U');`) to compare the two Dates.
Please note, that [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) maintains the key-value association while [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) does **not**.